# remove a node in xor linklist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I find the below code in C++ that insert and traverse a XOR linklist.

How do we remove a node ? As it seems when we remove a node, all the address of the node in the list need to get updated ?

Or my intuition is not correct this time ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xor-linked-list-a-memory-efficient-doubly-linked-list-set-1/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xor-linked-list-a-memory-efficient-doubly-linked-list-set-2/

Comment: Note that this is merely trading off one word of memory in each node, at the cost of one additional machine operation per node traversal.  Take a close look at the size of your data object, the size of your list, and the profile of inquiries.  Does the additional word of memory harm your application enough to warrant slowing the access time and maintenance times?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't update *all* of the addresses, merely the adjacent ones.  Look at the example list; let's extend it two more nodes:

```
z        A         B         C         D         E         F
   <–>  z⊕B  <–>  A⊕C  <->  B⊕D  <->  C⊕E  <->  D⊕F  <->
```

The *only* values that use the address of `C` are those for `B` and `D`.  If we remove `C`, we need only alter those values by the next ones moving in:

```
B.link = B.link ⊕ C ⊕ D
D.link = D.link ⊕ C ⊕ B
```

This gives us

```
z        A         B         D         E         F
   <–>  z⊕B  <–>  A⊕D  <->  B⊕E  <->  D⊕F  <->
```

Do you see how that works?  There's very little additional work involved: we have already traversed the list to `C` to find the item to remove; all we need do is keep the back-pointer as we move along (to operate on `B`), and then take one more step to access `D`.

Comment: I dont get it as why it doesnt set up a chain reaction. If the address of B,D change.  A's address depends on B and E address depends on D. so it changes also ?

Comment: I think I got it. Its A⊕D etc is the ptr being stored.